# Multiple UIAlerts on screen, some duplicating. Is there a fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

hey I have a method to iterate though an array and display a UIAlert for each item. code:

```
NSLog(@"Number of unlocked stickers is: %lu",(unsigned long)[unlockedStickers count]);
        for(Sticker *unlockedSticker in unlockedStickers){

            [self.stickerDictionary setObject:unlockedSticker forKey:unlockedSticker.title];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unlocked Sticker" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You unlocked the %@ sticker!",unlockedSticker.title] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];



        }
```

I tested it for an array with 4 sticker objects in it. The UIAlertViews are showing but there are more than 4, some are repeating. Not sure why this is happening. Does anyone know if there is a particular reason for this, or is it just buggy displaying more than one at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with an array of 4 strings. I only got 4 alerts...

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3"];
for (NSString *item in testArray) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:item delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
```

Set a log to count, and make sure you really have the amount you think you have.

Comment: Then take a step back. Put my code in. See if it works. If it does, substitute testArray for your array. If it works, substitute some other small part. If it doesn't, figure it out, then substitute the next part... and so on until all my parts are replaced with yours and it works.